# Get table ranking +- N items from MySQL (Flask-Backend)

Tags: mysql, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have following

**database `userPoints`**

```
+--------------+--------+
| id  | userId | points | 
+-----+--------+--------+
| 1   |   10   | 5      |   
| 2   |   10   | 6      |  
| 3   |   11   | 1      |  
| 4   |   12   | 10     | 
| 5   |   13   | 2      | 
| ... |   ...  | ...    | 
+-----+--------+--------+
```

And i want to display a ranking in my frontend which sums up the points per user and displays its position.

**UI:**

```
1.  UserId_10  |  11 Points
2.  UserId_12  |  10 Points
3.  UserId_13  |  12 Points
4.  ...
```

So far it would be really straight forward. But how can i get the list from the database when there are a lot of users and i want the position of a specific one:

**UI for userId_13 (+- 2 Users):**

```
1234. UserId_99  | 9999 Points 

1235. UserId_1   | 9001 Points

-----------------------------
1236. UserId_13  | 9000 Points
-----------------------------

1237. UserId_12  | 8024 Points

1237. UserId_11  | 8021 Points
```

Is there a way to do this directly with a query or do i have to load it in my backend (Flask) and then search in the array. The performance would be horrible because of 100k+ rows

Comment: The answer could depend on the version of MySQL you use, because only recent versions support [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). What does `SELECT @@version;` return?

Comment: It is Amazon RDS for MySQL currently version 5.6 but i think upgrading wouldn't be a problem ...

Comment: You can see that the answers so far are suggesting using window functions. I think the only way to do what you describe is to upgrade. FYI https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/upgrading-from-amazon-rds-for-mysql-version-5-5/ says that RDS for MySQL 5.6 is reaching its end-of-life in early 2021! So it's time for you to upgrade soon anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY points desc ) AS RowNum, *
              FROM     userpoints
            ) AS RowConstrainedResult
    WHERE   RowNum > 
            ((select rownum from  (select   user_Id,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY points desc ) AS RowNum
              FROM     userpoints
            ) as rownum where user_Id = 'userId_13') - 3)
    and
      RowNum <
            ((select rownum from  (select   user_Id,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY points desc ) AS RowNum
              FROM     userpoints
            ) as rownum where user_Id = 'userId_13') + 3)


ORDER BY RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have a solution for you. I don't know it efficient or not with your large data as you mentioned. So, here is my code =>

```
WITH CTE AS
(select t.UserID,
       DENSE_RANK() over (order by SumPoints desc) RNK
from (select DISTINCT t.UserID,
             SUM(points) over (partition by USERID) as SumPoints
       from @userPoints t
      ) t
) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE UserID=12
```

**Note:** This query works in MySQL 8, SQL SERVER and Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ranking for *all* records using aggregation and window functions:

```
select user_id, sum(points) as points,
       rank() over (order by sum(points) desc) as seqnum 
from userpoints
group by user_id;
```

If you want a specific one, then use a subquery:

```
select u.*
from (select user_id, sum(points) as points,
             rank() over (order by sum(points) desc) as seqnum 
      from userpoints
      group by user_id
     ) u
where user_id = ?
```